# Pycharm does not fold custom regions of code by default

Tags: pycharm

In Pycharm I tried to create custom code regions that would fold and stay folded upon reopening a file. To do so, I went to `File - Settings - Editor - General - Code Folding` and chose `Custom folding regions` in the `Collapse by default` section. However when I reopen Pycharm some of the custom regions are not folded and despite my repeated actions, the program will not permanently fold them. What could be wrong?

This behavior seems to happen only when I choose a region with existing fold regions. Then I get a message: `Overlapping fold region(s) exist`. And then I choose Remove (those existing regions, I understand) and the custom region I choose folds well. But in such cases when I see this message the folding region disappears when I reopen Pycharm. 
When this message is not there, the folding region remains upon reopening.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior happens when the custom region contains a start or end mark of the already existing region. Then the custom region conflicts with the existing region and the custom region is not saved.